# What should I use to display text/youtubeclips

Tags: html, css

I have no idea what to use to display my content here. I am trying to have text besides to a youtube embed video. Can I use tables to do this? If so can I make the text resize to fit perfectly in the `<td>` tag? Also, should I use a percentage or a fixed value height for this?

As I'm bad at html I don't know what else to tell you but I will answer all questions you need to ask as soon as I can.

http://jsfiddle.net/jnTda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use tables for this if I could help it, it makes your html content more cluttered and less comprehensive.  Perhaps you meant css tables, but this option would be less semantically correct.  I don't know exactly what your vision is, but try something like this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnTda/4/)

```
.video {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}
.descvid {height: 200px;}
article {
    width: 500px;
}
```

This would mean the height would need to be listed for the video description as shown in order to ensure that any content underneath does not wrap up into the space next to the video.

If you want to group them together with a shared background color (most often black), you could place both the video tag (I used a <div> tag as a placeholder for it) and the aside element in side of a larger div.  This would mean you'd specify dimensions for the video itself.  Then you would not need to reference the aside in your css and you could forgo assigning it a class:

[jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/jnTda/5/)

```
.video_section {
    display: inline-block;
}
.video {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}
```

As far as resizing the text automatically to fit the block next to the video, it may be possible, but I would suggest making an effort to keep your text bytes consistant in size.  Having font sizes that vary from page to page can irritate users when it results in fine-print.